# Vertical and Horizontal Headers in a table?

Tags: html, css, tabular

How would I get a table with both horizontal and vertical headers?

So e.g.

```
         header1 header2 header3 
header1    1        1      1
header2    2        2      2 
header3    3        3      3
```

Answer (score 34):

Like @UlrichSchwarz said, you can just use `<th>` instead of `<td>` in the first column.  Using scope, you can make it more semantically descriptive:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th scope="col">header1</th>
    <th scope="col">header2</th>
    <th scope="col">header3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">header 1</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">header 2</th>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">header 3</th>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

While you can still just `<th>` the entries in the first column, there is no column-equivalent of `<thead>`/`<tbody>` that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

easy. Just leave the first `td` in the first `tr` - empty

Answer (score -2):

You can make it with quite elementary HTML and CSS classes:

```css
table{border-collapse:collapse}
td{text-align:center;padding:5px;border:1px solid #000}
td.empty{border:0}
td.headt{font-weight:bold;background-color:#b7f926}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="empty"> </td>
<td class="headt">Header 1</td>
<td class="headt">Header 2</td>
<td class="headt">Header 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headt">Header 1</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headt">Header 2</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headt">Header 3</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is just a sketch/suggestion, but hopefully useful to compare for future readers :)